# The Dog of Allah?

Tags: hadith, tafseer, hadith-interpretation

assalaamu alaykum

I read a hadith in Tafsir al Tabari Sura An-Najim 53 verse 1 that Muhammad (saw) warned Abu Lahab or someone to fear the dog of Allah and it attacked him in Yemen and killed him? Is this hadith authentic is it true?

Here is my reference...

القول في تأويل قوله تعالى : وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى (1)
اختلف أهل التأويل في تأويل قوله ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) فقال بعضهم: عُنِيَ بالنجم: الثُّريا وعُنِي بقوله ( إِذَا هَوَى ) : إذا سقط, قالوا: تأويل الكلام: والثريا إذا سقطت.
* ذكر من قال ذلك:
حدثني محمد بن عمرو, قال: ثنا أبو عاصم, قال: ثنا عيسى; وحدثني الحارث, قال: ثنا الحسن, قال: ثنا ورقاء جميعا, عن ابن أبي نجيح, عن مجاهد, قوله: ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) قال: إذا سقطت الثريا مع الفجر.
حدثنا ابن حُميد. قال: ثنا مهران, عن سفيان ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) قال: الثريا، وقال مجاهد: ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) قال: سقوط الثريا.
حدثني محمد بن سعد, قال: ثني أبي, قال: ثني عمي, قال: ثني أبي, عن أبيه, عن ابن عباس, قوله: ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) قال: إذا انصبّ.
وقال آخرون: معنى ذلك: والقرآن إذا نـزل.
* ذكر من قال ذلك:
حدثني زياد بن عبد الله الحساني أبو الخطاب, قال: ثنا مالك بن &; 22-496 &; سعير, قال: ثنا الأعمش, عن مجاهد, في قوله ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) قال: القرآن إذا نـزل.
حدثنا بشر, قال: ثنا يزيد, قال: ثنا سعيد, عن قتادة ( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى * مَا ضَلَّ صَاحِبُكُمْ وَمَا غَوَى ) قال: قال عُتبة بن أبي لهب: كفرتُ بربّ النجم, فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: " أمَا تَخَافُ أنْ يَأكُلَكَ كَلْبُ اللهِ" قال: فخرج في تجارة إلى اليمن, فبينما هم قد عرَّسوا, إذ سمعَ صوتَ الأسد, فقال لأصحابه إني مأكول, فأحدقوا به, وضرب على أصمخّتهم فناموا, فجاء حتى أخذه, فما سمعوا إلا صوته.
حدثنا ابن عبد الأعلى, قال: ثنا محمد بن ثور, قال: ثنا معمر, عن قتادة " أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم تلا( وَالنَّجْمِ إِذَا هَوَى ) فقال ابن لأبي لهب حسبته قال: اسمه عُتبة: كفرت بربّ النجم, فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: " احْذَرْ لا يأكُلكَ كَلْبُ الله "; قال: فضرب هامته. قال: وقال ابن طاوس عن أبيه, أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: " ألا تَخاف أنْ يُسلِّطَ اللهُ عَلَيْك كَلْبَهُ؟" فخرج ابن أبي لهب مع ناس فى سفر حتى إذا كانوا في بعض الطريق سمعوا صوت الأسد. فقال: ما هو إلا يريدني, فاجتمع أصحابه حوله وجعلوه في وسطهم, حتى إذا ناموا جاء الأسد فأخذه من بينهم. وكان بعض أهل المعرفة بكلام العرب من أهل البصرة يقول: عنى بقوله: ( وَالنَّجْمِ ) والنجوم. وقال: ذهب إلى لفظ الواحد, وهو في المعنى الجميع, واستشهد لقوله ذلك بقول راعي الإبل:
فَبَـاتَتْ تَعُـدُّ النَّجْـمَ فـي مُسـتَحيرَةٍ
سَــريعٌ بِــأيْدي الآكـلِينَ جُمُودُهـا (1)

### والصواب من القول في ذلك عندي ما قاله مجاهد من أنه عنى بالنجم في هذا الموضع: الثريا, وذلك أن العرب تدعوها النجم, والقول الذي قاله من حكينا عنه من أهل البصرة قول لا نعلم أحدا من أهل التأويل قاله, وإن كان له وجه, فلذلك تركنا القول به.

الهوامش :
(1) البيت لراعي الإبل النميري عبيد بن أيوب ( مجاز القرآن لأبي عبيدة الورقة 230 من المصورة 26059) قال عند قوله تعالى ( والنجم إذا هوى ) : قسم ، والنجم : النجوم ، ذهب إلى لفظ الواحد وهو في معنى الجمع ، قال راعي الإبل : " وباتت تعد النجم ... " البيت . وفي مستحيرة : في إهالة ، جعلها طافية ، لأنها من شحم . وقال ابن قتيبة في كتاب المعاني الكبير ، طبع الهند .
وقال الراعي وذكر امرأة أضافها : فباتت ... البيت . مستحيرة : جفنة قد تحير فيها الدسم ، فهي ترى فيها النجوم لصفاء الإهالة ، وأراد بقوله تعد النجم : الثرياء ، والعرب تسمى الثريا النجم . قال :
طلــــع النجــــم عشــــاء
ابتغــــى الـــراعي كســـاء
وقال التبريزي في شرح حماسة أبي تمام ( 4 : 39 ) قال أبو العلاء : كان بعض الناس يجعل " تعد " هنا من العدد ، أي أن هذه المرأة تعد النجم في الجفنة المستحيرة ، أي المملوءة ، لأنها ترى خيال النجوم فيها ، وقد يجوز هذا الوجه ، وقد يحتمل أن يكون " تعد " في معنى تحسب وتظن ، والمراد أن المرأة تحسب النجم في الجفنة ، لما تراه من بياض الشحم أ . هـ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have read your quoted source very intensely, so if you check the hadith and what the man feared from you may find your answer: Our Messenger (Peace be upon him) didn't mean that Allah has a dog rather than to scare his enemy by a possible attack of one of the dog-like animals. In Arabic language the word dog [كلب](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/home.php?word=%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A8&lang_name=ar-ar&type_word=0&dspl=0) is often used as a synonym of lion أسد or more general a beast:

> و الكَلْبُ كلُّ سَبُعٍ عقور ؛ وربما وُصف به ،، والجمع كِلاَبٌ ، وأَكْلُبٌ .  (al-mo'jam al-Moheet)

and as you may find in the hadith that disbeliever heard a lion not a dog. Some therefore said that dog of Allah meanas lion, but I doubt if one should take this literally and would say that our Messenger has frighten him by saying "Aren't you afraid of one of Allah's beasts".

On the other hand none except at-Tabari has quoted this strange story to support his commentary of this verse. And even at-Tabari just quoted it for the sake of an academic honesty while he was favoring the report or explanation of Mujahid saying an-Najm refers to the Pleiades, as you quoted:

> والصواب من القول في ذلك عندي ما قاله مجاهد من أنه عنى بالنجم في هذا الموضع: الثريا

And in the context of this Verse the more and most quoted hadith is this sahih [hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/17/5).

And Allah knows best!